# Laravel New User Registration via API POST Fail

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt, postman

I use Postman to try creating a new user with email and password to the database through laravel

but I do not receive the token after the user is created succesfuly and I receive these instead:

```
    <!doctype html>
   <html class="theme-light">
   <!--
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\JWT::fromUser() must be an instance of Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject, instance of App\User given, called in /Users/ahmed/laravelapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 261 in file /Users/ahmed/laravelapi/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/JWT.php on line 88

#0 /Users/ahmed/laravelapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(261): Tymon\JWTAuth\JWT->fromUser(Object(App\User))
#1 /Users/ahmed/laravelapi/app/Http/Controllers/APIRegisterController.php(33): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('fromUser', Array)
#2 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\APIRegisterController->register(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /Users/ahmed/laravelapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /Users/ahmed/laravelapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('register', Array)
#5 /Users/ahmed/laravelapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(239): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\APIRegisterController), 'register')
```

here is the code inside APIRegisterController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use JWTFactory;
use JWTAuth;
use Validator;
use Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class APIRegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request -> all(),[
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        # code...
        return response()->json($validator->errors());
    }

    User::create([
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->get('password'))
    ]);

    $user = User::first();
    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

    return Response::json(compact('token'));
}
}
```

Here is User.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];

}
```

Although I receive these errors in the laravel project :

Validator: Undefined type
JWTAuth : Undefined type
Response: Undefined type

Can anyone help me to make successful post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1094) pavinthan asked on Github, you have [to update](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/quick-start/#update-your-user-model) your `User` model to implement the `Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject` interface:

```php
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User implements JWTSubject
{
    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added User.php model to code. Do you mean replacing it with the code you presented?

Comment: No, you need to implement the JWTSubject interface as described here: https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/quick-start/#update-your-user-model

Comment: Worked like a charm man and finally got my token. Thank you a lot

Comment: Glad you got it working! Good luck with your project.